# Passing a value to a modal in Django

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a delete confirmation modal after clicking on a delete button on a table, generated by a number of objects from a Django view:

```
...
{% for i in items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-delete-item">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
....
```

What I have in the modal is something like this:

```
<div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modal-delete-item" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        ....
        <button href="{% url 'remove_quote_item' i.pk %}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Oui, je confirme.</button>
        ....
</div>
```

How can I use the "i" variable in the modal since I am outside the loop, can I use anything to reference that variable into the modal? Or probably use javascript to perform that action? Or is there something I can do with jinja itself?

Thanks!

Comment: you can do this by javascript and it will be esy to use ajax to send data to server if you wish to use javascript

Answer (score 1):

**Best Practice**

Use Ajax to send a request to the server with the id number you want
to delete.

**Bad Practice**

It is Bad Practice but you can solve this issue.

```
{% for i in items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
    <td><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-delete-item-{{ i.id }}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
...........
<div class="modal modal-blur fade" id="modal-delete-item-{{ i.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        ....
        <button href="{% url 'remove_quote_item' i.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Oui, je confirme.</button>
        ....
</div>

.........
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Any chance you could help me out with the Ajax? I don't have much experience in it.

Comment: Yeah it's bad practice because if you have 40 items in the loop, you will end up with 40 modals which isn't ideal

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ajax to send request to server with id as data.
2. in delete function of view.py, return 0 if record with given id is deleted from database or return 1 if not deleted or any other error occurs.
3. create a hidden div element above the table, if response is 0 then remove that row from table using and show that div element both using javascript.